# new variable points to old variable

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

Disclaimer: I'm very new to C. I tried to find an answer to this but my google-fu has failed miserably, since I don't exactly know the terms I should use for the search...

At the moment, I'm having a rather unexpected problem, where the code `int a = 100;` makes an integer inside a struct also change value.

From the debugger, I can see that both a and s->pos point to the same value. Here is a sanitized version of my code.

```
typedef struct {
    char data[4096];
    int start;
    int end;
} buffer;

typedef struct {
    int * data;
    int length;
} data_format;

buffer * create_buffer() {
    buffer result;
    result.start = -1;
    return &result;
}

data_format * method(buffer * s) {
    data_format result = (data_format) { malloc(100), 0 };
    ... // POINT1
    int a = 100;
    ... // POINT2
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    buffer * s = create_buffer();
    data_format * df = method(s);
}
```

From the debugger, I can see that in the line marked with `// POINT1`, `a` is -1; at `// POINT2`, both `a` and `s->start` are now 100.

Shouldn't the `int` declaration create a variable in a memory spot not yet used by anything?

Comment: I suspect in a function you have not shown, you are allocating your buffer `s` in a similar fashion to `result` and then doing `return &s`  or something similar, as it appears that would be how you are going to return result from the function shown.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, s is probably pointing to the beginning of method's stack and the malloc, 0 and 100 are overlapping with buffer.data, start and end. Though one cannot be sure as the code posted is incomplete. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: @iagreen I haev just edited the question. I do indeed create s as you said. But I fail to see how `a` can be assigned the same memory point as `s->start`
@aib My code is messy and full of other stuff. However, my edits should make the code compilable now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are violating the scope of a local variable by returning its address in `create_buffer`.

Local variables are created on the stack, and the stack is reused on each function call.  By returning the address of `result` in `create_buffer` you are saving the address of a section of memory that C has only reserved for your use for the duration of the `create_buffer` function.  When it terminates, that memory is reused.  In this case, when you call `method` is it aligning with your `s` variable.  You need to dynamically allocate your return variables with `malloc`

Depending on your compiler, you should be getting a warning from it about returning the address of a local variable.

Comment: Thanks!
For now I changed `buffer result = malloc(sizeof(buffer))`. Should I make ceate_buffer return a real buffer instead of a pointer?

Comment: No, still return the pointer, change you declaration to a pointer -- `buffer *result = malloc(sizeof(buffer))`.  You will have to do the same with your `data_format result`, too, and you will have to initialized you structure elements one by one, because I do not think the `{}` initializers work on dynamically allocated objects.

Answer (score 2):

Please excuse my ignorance, but in C, is something like `create_buffer` even possible? You're creating `result` on the stack and then returning a pointer to it. Doesn't `result` get destroyed after `create_buffer` gets executed? So now `s` is pointing to 'garbage'. Maybe, like aib said in the comments, the address in memory it's pointing to happens to be the address of `a`.

Instead, `create_buffer` should also `malloc` the `buffer`, then you can safely return a pointer to that.

Comment: You can do it — see the code in the question — but it leads to _undefined behaviour_ which means anything can happen and you can't complain.  The variable `result` goes out of scope, which means its memory can be reused for other purposes.  It probably isn't formally destroyed (no writing nulls over it or anything like that), but its value is completely unreliable.

Comment: You're not ignorant in this; you're *observant*. This is C so it is completely "possible" to run off into la-la-undefined-behavior land with belief that everything is fine when, in fact, it isn't (case in point, the OP's post). You're correct that something with lifetime *outside* the function (could be a malloc, a global, etc.) must be used; not a local-scope buffer address.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm well aware, I admit to poor wording on my part. Although I didn't know the detail of it not necessarily being destroyed. That's my understanding in C++. I imagine different rules apply in C, or maybe my understanding is simply incorrect. Thanks for alerting me to that :)

WhozCraig Thanks :)